# Is there some technique to plot complex functions by hand?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

Is there some technique to plot complex functions by hand?

Particularly, consider e.g.

$$x=\exp(t)\cos(t), y=\exp(t)\sin(t)$$

This is equivalent to $e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))$ along line $y=x$, just parametrized.

WA gives:

[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D(exp(t))*cos(t),+y%3Dexp(t)*sin(t)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D(exp(t))*cos(t),%20y%3Dexp(t)*sin(t))

Comment: What do you mean by a complex function?

Comment: Maybe "complicated"?

Comment: @copper.hat This is equivalent to $e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))$ along line $y=x$, just parametrized.

Comment: You mean plot a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$. Generally, a complex function refers to $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it's relatively easy.  The (unit speed) unit circle is given by
$$c(t)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(t)\\\sin(t)\end{pmatrix}.$$
The curve in question is of the form
$r(t)\cdot c(t)$ where $r(t)=e^t$. That changes the radius of the unit circle so we'll get a sort of spiral.